# How to call API once and send data to multiple JS files

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, fetch-api

I am creating a website which queries a database.

I have created a API get method using nodejs express to get data from the database.

Something like this:

```
app.get('/getLatestData', (req, res) => {
     var dataArray;
     //some code here to get the array
     res.send(dataArray);
});
```

so if I call `getLatestData` I would get an array that has what I need which we can say is something like:

```
dataArray = [humanName: abc,  humanAge: 25, humanWeight:.....etc]
```

Using this I am creating a web site where I can display information such as a graph of his weight over time or some text such as his name and age as a string.

HTML file:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="text" id="text2">
            <script src="sketch.js"></script>
        </div>
        <div class="chart">
            <canvas id="bar-chart" width="500" height="500">
                <script src="bargraph.js"></script>
            </canvas>
        </div>
</div>
```

Now as you can see in this case I have two JavaScript files: bargraph.js and sketch.js, the problem I am having is that in each of the JavaScript files I am querying the API `getLatestData` like this:

```
fetch('/getLatestDevice')
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(data => {
            newWeight = data.eight
         })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('error')
        });
```

I don't want to constantly keep calling this API fetch in all these different JS files because the latestdata can change and I might be accessing different instances of it, is there a way where I can call the API get once put it in a variable and transfer that to the different files instead of doing it in each individually?

Answer (score 0):

In JS top level declared variables are global which is a blessing and a curse. You can use this to your advantage. Declare a global variable and Save the response of the API call in said variable. Then you can access it in all of your JS files

Comment: where would i declare the global variable if i have multiple JS files?

Comment: For convenience declare it in the first file u import to the html

Comment: or just have every page check for `window.variableNameHere` and go forward. now if you want this to be a reactive process, i.e. the other portions all update whenever the variable is updated, that's some trickier business

Comment: Oh so i just call the api in my first JS file like:   var thisDataArray = getLatestData() and then i can access thisDataArray in the other files

Comment: Setting it this way won't work because of the async nature of the api call. Declare it on top but set it inside the fetch response. Jhecht method works also

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the result of the fetch method to a global variable like so:

```
window.latestDevice = undefined; // Global accessible variable
const request = fetch('/getLatestDevice').then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    }).then((data) => {
      window.latestDevice = data;
    });
```

Then you should be able to get `window.latestDevice` data from your JS files.